# how to find and write a frequency of occurrence of words inside text data into csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp

How Can I create csv file containing  words and its frequency of occurrence in python  .

I removed the stop words, tokenized and countvectorized the  text data

My code

```
 data['Clean_addr'] = data['Adj_Addr'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item.lower() for item in x.split()]))
        data['Clean_addr']=data['Clean_addr'].apply(lambda x:"".join([item.lower() for item in x if  not  item.isdigit()]))
        data['Clean_addr']=data['Clean_addr'].apply(lambda x:"".join([item.lower() for item in x if item not in string.punctuation]))
        data['Clean_addr'] = data['Clean_addr'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item.lower() for item in x.split() if item not in (new_stop_words)]))
        cv = CountVectorizer( max_features = 200,analyzer='word')
        cv_addr = cv.fit_transform(data.pop('Clean_addr'))
```

Sample Dump of the File I am using

https://www.dropbox.com/s/allhfdxni0kfyn6/Test.csv?dl=0

```
**Expected output**
Word       Freq
Industry    40
Limited     23
House       45
flat        56
```

Comment: What is expected output? Do you need `df1 = pd.DataFrame(cv_addr.todense(), columns=cv.get_feature_names())` ?

Comment: @jezrael  I need  the word and its corresponding frequency . I updated the sample output in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `DataFrame` first and then `sum`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(cv_addr.todense(), columns=cv.get_feature_names())
df1 = df1.sum().rename_axis('Word').reset_index(name='Freq')
```